# There is an appropriate time standard for the display of a splash screen for mobile apps or not?

Tags: mobile, splash-screen

Or it's depends on each case? I tested here with 2 second and found it very long. But a coworker told me that 2 second is the default. Is it true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any splash screen that you have should be displayed for **as short a time as you can** (within reason).  It isn't content and it isn't what users are interested in, so forcing them to look at it for some pre-determined amount of time (when it's not technically necessary) results in a poorer UX.

So if you can load up the app in 0.5 seconds, then show the splash screen for 0.5 seconds.  If it takes 4 seconds to load up the app, then show it for 4 seconds.